# TabCtrl_InsertItem: do we need to keep memory of the text alive?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

For [`TabCtrl_InsertItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760678.aspx), do we need keep [`pszText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760554.aspx) member points to valid memory or will the OS copy the text so that we can straight away clear the text?

```
TCITEM tcItem = { TCIF_TEXT };
CString strText;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    strText.Format(_T("Tab %d"), i+1);
    tcItem.pszText = strText;          // option 1
    tcItem.pszText = _tcsdup(strText); // option 2
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(i, &tcItem);
}
```

How can we know which is the correct one for this function and other functions in future?
I couldn't find it in MSDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operating system will copy the string to an internal data structure. You do not need to maintain the backing character array. You can free it as soon as the function call is complete.

In general, this is the case for any Windows API function that receives a string. You're right, it doesn't say it explicitly in the MSDN documentation, but most Windows developers already know this. MSDN *will* call out explicitly when this is *not* true. I can't think of an example off the top of my head—if it ever occurs, it is quite rare.

Answer (score 2):

This example, [How to Create a Tab Control in the Main Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298367.aspx), would suggest that you don't need to keep hold of the memory after you have added the tab.

Just to add, even if the documentation is not explicit, it is normally fairly easy to find examples.

Comment: You are right in this case. But the problem with basing things on examples is that there are a lot of *wrong* examples out there! Unfortunately, there are even a few on MSDN. String handling is a common bugbear.